# How can I use sp-core v7.0.0

Tags: polkadot

I have an error while cargo build -- release on polkadot v0.9.31

```
error: failed to select a version for `parity-util-mem`.
    ... required by package `sp-core v6.0.0`
    ... which satisfies dependency `sp-core = "^6.0.0"` of package `sp-keyring v6.0.0`
    ... which satisfies dependency `sp-keyring = "^6.0.0"` of package `integration-tests v4.0.0-dev (/eric/VoiceBanBackend/integration-tests)`
versions that meet the requirements `^0.11.0` are: 0.11.0

the package `parity-util-mem` links to the native library `parity-util-mem-ban-duplicates`, but it conflicts with a previous package which links to `parity-util-mem-ban-duplicates` as well:
package `parity-util-mem v0.12.0`
    ... which satisfies dependency `parity-util-mem = "^0.12.0"` of package `sc-informant v0.10.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v0.9.31#7a4e5163)`
    ... which satisfies git dependency `sc-informant` of package `sc-service v0.10.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v0.9.31#7a4e5163)`
    ... which satisfies git dependency `sc-service` of package `node-template v4.0.0-dev (/eric/VoiceBanBackend/node)`
Only one package in the dependency graph may specify the same links value. This helps ensure that only one copy of a native library is linked in the final binary. Try to adjust your dependencies so that only one package uses the links ='parity-util-mem' value. For more information, see https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/resolver.html#links.
```

I saw niklasad1's commit, it is still under review.
I'd like to use the latest polkadot version that include sp-core v7.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Errors like this happen when you mess up the `Cargo.lock` file. (which you shouldn't do)

You should reset your branch, removing any changes from origin, and try compiling again.